# How can I export 1920X1080 to 320X240 without losing quality?

Tags: video-editor, video-quality

I have created a mo graph video using After Effects and Premier in HD 1920X1080. The client wants a much smaller version in 320x240 but every time I render out the smaller version pixilates.

Is there a way I can fix this

Comment: Depending on which device you client uses, it is a matter of the used codec as well. Try use different codecs and compare results!

Comment: That's a bit like the client wanting you to fax them a copy of an oil painting, and then complaining that there's no colour. They're basically asking the impossible.

Comment: Why do they want a smaller version?  What are they trying to do with it?  What are the reasons for their constraint?  All of these are critical pieces of information for meaningfully answering your question.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you try, you will lose quality as you are reducing the resolution significantly. So you are creating each new pixel from an aggregate of 36 - and depending on how you do that it can look okay or terrible, but it will not look anywhere near as good as the original. There is no way to avoid this.

Experiment with the settings for down sizing - for your video some may work better than others.

Comment: thanks. i did try all settings i know but nothing works